# Project Euler # 10 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, primes

I'm trying to solve Problem 10 in Project Euler, and while I thought I had it, its saying my answer is incorrect. The question is as follows:

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>   Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

And my code:

```
int sum;
@interface Prime : NSObject
-(BOOL)isPrime:(int)arg1;
@end

@implementation Prime
-(BOOL)isPrime:(int)arg1 {
    if (arg1 == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Given 1");
        return NO;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < arg1; i++) {
        if (arg1 % i == 0) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    sum += arg1;
    return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Prime* primeObject = [[Prime alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
            [primeObject isPrime:i];
        }
        NSLog(@"Sum of primes is %i", sum);
    }

}
```

This code outputs 'Sum of primes is 1179908154' which Project Euler says is incorrect. Help?

Comment: Try initializing `sum` to 0.

Comment: Efficiency is probably not the focus but `for (int i = 2; i < arg1; i++)` loop can be `for (int i = 3; i < sqrt(arg1); i += 2)`.Saves a ton of cycles. Just check if it is divisible by 2 as an edge case in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the sum does not fit into a 32-bit integer. You should use `long long` instead.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!! It didn't occur to me that int would be too small :p

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, you should try to:

- Initialise the `sum` variable to 0.
- Try not to use a global variable like `sum` that can be accessed from anywhere, in this case do the sum in the main loop instead of in the `isPrime` method.

Maybe that'll give you the right answer.

Comment: Yes, it is really strange that the summation is being done in the `isPrime:` method.

Comment: A global variable is initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int` for getting result, so it is wrong.
I'm using `long int` instead, that is enough for this case.

Here is my code, and it works fine:

```
    int inputNumber = 2000000;
    long int result = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < inputNumber; i++) {
        BOOL isPrime = YES;
        for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i%j==0) {
                isPrime = NO;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            result += i;
        }
    }
```

Result is: `142913828922`